# Windows 10 - No headphone recognized/showed when plugged in

Tags: windows-10, audio

The sound went off from my headphone while in game. Speaker still seems to work. I tried update RealTek HD audio driver and installing the driver that I downloaded from its website, but none works. I noticed that headphone disappears from device manager->audio inputs and outputs, which only left microphone and speakers. I also ran the sound troubleshoot, this is what it says:

> The device does not appear to be plugged in.  Check the connection, plug in the device, then click next

Apparently I already plugged in the headphone but windows doesn't detect it. Why? This problem bugged me for days.

Comment: Probably an hardware problem.

Comment: Yes it seems like the audio device in your computer is at fault...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could find device manager :), but maybe helpful for others:
Check in device manager (right click on Windows logo or WIN-Key + R >> type in "devmgmt.msc") sections "Audio, video and gamecontroller" and "Audio in and outputs". See if you device is under "Audio in and outputs" - probably not. Then find Realtek High Definition Audio >> right click >> properties (click on "Config Settings with the UAC logo beside and enter admin password). Go under "driver" and try "update driver". It's probably easier to select the "look in windows update" option. If nothing happens, deinstall the device and check http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/ to get the newest Realtek Driver (take the one for Win 10 of course, maybe that was the problem).

Unfortunately the sudden loss of audio, but the fact that microphones and speakers still seem to work could (could =/= does) mean a broken internal connection on the headset, but this is unlikely. What headset do you use? USB or mic and speaker seperate?

Comment: I'm using Edifier H840 headphone 3.5mm jack. The mic and speaker are built in on the laptop.

Comment: So could you please test the H840 on another audio source e.g. your smartphone, a HIFI to see if it works or not? Best way to solve problems: imagine a route to go Headphone (speakers) >> Cable >> input jack (btw., are you using a front input or direct mobo?) >> Check if HD Audio cable on your motherboard is fitted correctly >> Then software (e.g. drivers)